# How to display database data on a dynamic graph/chart

Tags: database, dynamic, graph, charts, html

In my database I have a simple table that contains values showing the basic physical activity of a user. There are just 4 columns in this table - username, timestamp, active and sedentary. It should be updated for a user every hour, with the amount of minutes they are active in the hour stored under active, and non-active under sedentary.

My question is how can I display this data for a user on a webpage? As the database is always being updated with new values each hour, how would I go about creating a dynamic chart, graph or some other format that reads from the database and display the activity of the user effectively? Any code examples would be much appreciated too, thanks in advance.

Also I don't have admin access to the web server I am using so I can't install any components or software on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not really express any technical preference about language, framework or database.

Regardless of the server technology, you could use a mix of

1. For appealing **chart presentation**: [Google visualisation](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html) Or your own SVG drawing skill.
2. For **periodic refresh**:

   2.a

   `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">`

   To rely on the browser to refresh periodically.

   Or

   2.b
   Ajax periodic calls to the server in XML/JSON

These are just a few ideas for simple/affordable development techniques

But there are many other techniques.
Have a look at [this](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/03/09/50-free-resources-for-charts-and-graphs-solution/) list for charts for instance.

Comment: The database is SQL server 2008 and I'm making the webpage using ASP.net - C Sharp. I don't mind what language I would have to use to display the chart on the webpage or so much the page refresh, just need to figure out how to display the data, I'll take a look at your links and reply how I get on, cheers.

Comment: Hi, I have similar situation as you described in the question. Can you please share with me how you solve it. Any suggestions? thanks.